# Merge files only if they go deeper than two levels

Tags: gulp

I have this file structure:

- Root

  - Folder1

    - Subfolder1.1

      - Subfolder1.1.1

        - file_1.1.1.1.js
        - file_1.1.1.2.js
      - file_1.1.1.js
      - file_1.1.2.js
    - Subfolder1.2
  - Folder2
  - Folder3

I'm trying to accomplish the following gulp task that will take the root directory, in this case, the Root folder, and generate the following structure:

- Root

  - Folder1

    - Subfolder1.1

      - Subfolder1.1.1.min.js
      - file_1.1.1.min.js
      - file_1.1.2.min.js
    - Subfolder1.2
  - Folder2
  - Folder3

As you can see, the files that are directly in the second level, e.g. Subfolder1.1, are just minified. All the files that go deeper than two levels will be concatenated and named after the second level folder containing them.

Is this possible to accomplish in gulp, and if it is, can anybody give me a clue on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to do it, here is the code:

```
gulp.task('task',
function() {
    // The input root dir
    var root = 'root_in';

    // The output root dir
    var rootOut = 'root_out'

    // first get all the folders in the in the root directory
    var folders = fs.readdirSync(root)
        .filter(function(file) {
            return fs.statSync(path.join(root, file)).isDirectory();
        });

    return folders.map(function(folder) {
        // get the files inside each folder
        var files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(root, folder));
        files.map(function(file) {

            // in case it is a directory, concat all the files 
            if (fs.statSync(path.join(root, folder, file)).isDirectory()) {
                return gulp.src(path.join(root, folder, file, '/**/*.js'))
                    .pipe(uglify())
                    .pipe(gulp_concat(file + '.js'))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(root, folder)))
            }
            // if it is a regular file, just uglify it and output
            else {
                return gulp.src(path.join(root, folder, file))
                    .pipe(uglify())
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(rootOut, folder)));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you to [run some tasks by folder](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md).
Or maybe you can find some help on [building such a thing yourself by iterating over directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149966/iterating-over-directories-with-gulp).

Comment: the file structure is dynamic in my case, it is not fixed as stated and can change. I cannot add a task for every folder