# How to write correct way for multiple folders in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I have next structure.

```
    html5
     |_33
       |_2.2.0
         |_js
           |_file1.js
           |_file2.js
           |_file3.js
     |_22
       |_2.2.0
         |_js
           |_file1.js
           |_file2.js
           |_file3.js
     |_24
       |_2.2.0
         |_js
           |_file1.js
           |_file2.js
           |_file3.js
    html5prod
     |_33
       |_2.2.0
         |_js
           |_file1(minify).js
           |_file2(minify).js
           |_file3(minify).js
```

From folder html5 I want move minified files in html5prod.

If its one folder I can write

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
   return gulp.src('./html5/**/*.js')
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(concat('min.js', {newLine: ';'}))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./html5prod/24/2.2.0/js'));
});
```

How write destination for all folders in this string?

**.pipe(gulp.dest('./html5prod/24/2.2.0/js'));**

Result will be next,
 from folder html5 > 24 go in html5prod > 24,
 from html5 > 33 go in html5prod > 33

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy directories recursively with gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038014/how-do-i-copy-directories-recursively-with-gulp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over directories with Gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149966/iterating-over-directories-with-gulp)

Answer (score 0):

Check this recipe from gulp docs [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md)

it get all folders and start iterate over folders and direct the resulted scripts to destination.